# initramfs error when trying to reboot to newly installed Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: initramfs, busybox

I got an initramfs error when trying to reboot to newly installed Ubuntu 22.04.

[image]
<sup>**ACPI BIOS error**</sup>

[image]
<sup>**ALERT!  /dev/sda2 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!**</sup>

Comment: Looks like you installed Ubuntu on a removable disk, then removed that disk. Either way, there is an insufficient amount of actionable information here to work with. Could you [edit] the question to include the exact steps you followed, including which devices were connected and disconnected during the process?

Comment: @matigo In the 2nd screenshot I can see `/dev/sda1` but `/dev/sda2` is nowhere to be found (or possibly removed). This happens occasionally and a canonical duplicate question for this situation exists, but meanwhile this question is unclear.